# Find out whether string A can be shifted to get string B

Tags: javascript, algorithm, strings, functional-programming, comparative-review

The task:

> Given two strings A and B, return whether or not A can be shifted some
>   number of times to get B.
>
> For example, if A is abcde and B is cdeab, return true. If A is abc
>   and B is acb, return false.

Solution 1:

```
const haveSameLength = (a, b) => a.length === b.length;
const isSame = (a, b) => a === b;
const isFullyShifted = a => a === 0;
const shiftStringBy = i => a => `${a.substring(i)}${a.substring(0, i)}`;

const isSameAfterShifting = (strA, strB, items) => {
  if (strA.length === 0 || strB.length ===0) { return false }
  if (!haveSameLength(strA, strB)) { return false }
  if (isSame(strA, strB)) { return true }
  if (isFullyShifted(items)) { return false }

  return isSameAfterShifting(strA, shiftStringBy(1)(strB), --items)
}

const str1 = 'abcde';
const str2 = 'cdeab';

console.log(isSameAfterShifting(str1, str2, str2.length));
```

Solution 2

```
const isSameAfterShifting2 = (strA, strB) => {
  if (strA.length === 0 || strB.length ===0) { return false }
  if (!haveSameLength(strA, strB)) { return false }
  const arrB = strB.split('');
  const firstLetterA = strA.substring(0, 1);

  let shiftIndex = arrB.indexOf(firstLetterA);
  if (shiftIndex === -1) { return false }
  while (shiftIndex < arrB.length) {
    const strBShifted = `${strB.substring(shiftIndex)}${strB.substring(0, shiftIndex)}`;
    if (strA === strBShifted) { return true }
    shiftIndex++;
  }
  return false;
}

console.log(isSameAfterShifting2('abc', 'acb'));
```

Which one is more readable and easier to understand for you?

Comment: I think this needs only a one liner `const isShifted = (a, b) => a.length === b.length && a === b || (a + a).includes(b);`

Comment: This is quite genius. Lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the `String` is empty with `!str` instead of `strA.length === 0`,

`console.log(''); // false`

i think `haveSameLength` and `isSame` are extras, you can write `srtA.length === strB.length` and it would still be readable,

you can get the first letter with a simpler `strA[0]` instead of `strA.substring(0, 1);`

> Which one is more readable and easier to understand for you?

a loop is easier to read and understand than a recursive function,

But the hole approach seems like it can be simpler using a `for` loop, [Array.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) , here's what i would suggest :

You can generate an array of combinations moving the letters one index at a time,
for a string `abc` you would have `['abc, bca', 'cba']`, see if one of the resulting array entries euqals the second string :

```js
const isSameAfterShifting = (str1, str2) => {
  // check if the strings are empty or has different lengths
  if (!str1 || !str2 || str1.length !== str2.length) return false;

  // check if the strings are the same
  if (str1 === str2) return true;

  // generate the array 
  let combos = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < str1.length; i++) {
    let c = str1.slice(i) + str1.slice(0, i);
    combos.push(c);
  }

  // for a string 'abc'
  // combos = ['abc', bca', 'cab']

  // check if the array has one of its entries equal to the second string  
  return combos.some(s => s === str2);
}

console.log( isSameAfterShifting('abc', 'cab') );
console.log( isSameAfterShifting('abc', 'cabaaa') );
console.log( isSameAfterShifting('abc', 'bac') );
```

you can replace the `for` loop with [Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

```js
const isSameAfterShifting = (str1, str2) => {
  // check if the strings are empty or has different lengths
  if (!str1 || !str2 || str1.length !== str2.length) return false;

  // check if the strings are the same
  if (str1 === str2) return true;

  // generate the array
  let combos = Array.from({
    length: str1.length
  }, (_, i) => str1.slice(i) + str1.slice(0, i));

  // for a string 'abc'
  // combos = ['abc', bca', 'cab']

  // check if the array has one of its entries equal to the second string
  return combos.some(s => s === str2);
};

console.log(isSameAfterShifting("abc", "cab"));
console.log(isSameAfterShifting("abc", "cabaaa"));
console.log(isSameAfterShifting("abc", "bac"));
```